# Sorting Innerhits results using Nest

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, nest, amazon-elasticsearch

I'm having trouble figuring out the correct usage of `.Sort()` for inner hits.  If I have a document structure like:

```
{
  "id": "whatever",
  "sales": [
    {
      "startsOn": "2022-05-01T00:00:00"
      "endsOn": "2022-05-31T23:59:59"
      "discountPercent": 0.10
    },
    {
      "startsOn": "2022-06-01T00:00:00"
      "endsOn": "2022-06-31T23:59:59"
      "discountPercent": 0.15
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to order the innerResults by `startsOn` descending and my InnerHits code looks something like:

```
  client.SearchAsync<Product>(x =>
    x.Query(q => 
      q.Nested(n => 
        n.Path(p => p.sales)
        .Query(q => q.DateRange( /* misc date range*/))
        .InnerHits(ih => ih.Name("sorted_Sales")))));
```

I tried adding `.Sort()` after the `.Name()` but I get a

> FieldSortDescriptor does not contain a definition for sales and no accessible exensiont method *yada yada*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below will sort inner hits with descending order using `startsOn` field.

```
.InnerHits(ih => ih
  .Name("sorted_Sales")
  .Sort(s => s
    .Descending(d => d.sales.FirstOrDefault()!.startsOn))))))
```